# delete from the request oracle all that is further words "info"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have an oracle request.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  
           to_char(to_date('1970/01/01 00:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') + rep.value_number/86400000, 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') ||' '|| nvl(trns.representation, '')  transaction_number 
    FROM IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION rep
        LEFT join txn 
       on rep.VALUE_NUMBER = txn.transaction_value_number
        
        LEFT  JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_EVENT_LOG evlog
           ON rep.parent = evlog.id
         LEFT JOIN IOT_DEVICE_EVENT ev
           ON evlog.device_event = ev.id
         LEFT JOIN IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_TRANSACTIONS trns
           ON rep.value_number = trns.name
    WHERE lower(rep.key) = 'transaction'
          AND rep.value_number <> 0
          AND rownum = 1
```

This query is easy I am looking for a deadline with some information. This query works, but I want to remove something from the answer. The answer I have is one template:

```
2021.01.25 13:48:15 weight: 0 max weight: 35000 min weight: 1000 info: 37
```

I want to remove the word INFO from this answer and everything after that word. I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: look at SUBSTR function

Answer (score 1):

You would use regexp_substr function like below

```sql
regexp_substr(your_answer_column, '(.*?)info.*?$', 1, 1, 'i', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing this is to use instr and substr.

```
Substr(your_string, 1, instr(your_string, 'info') - 1)
```

Note that this will perform better than `regexp` as `regexp` comes with its own complexity and do not perform well compared to `substr` and `instr`.